# Where should the prisma folder be placed in a Nuxt application

Tags: prisma, nuxt3

As I discover Nuxt and more generally node applications, I have a bunch of questions that bother me more than a little.
At the moment I am wondering why in the tutorial I follow, the author placed the prisma folder like this:

```
/
    server
        database
           migrations
           repositories
              schema.prisma
```

In most other reading I had, and even in the prisma doc, the suggested structure is as follows:

```
/
    prisma
        migrations
        schema.prisma
    server
```

My question is does it matter to have the prisma stuff under server folder or not ?
If yes, what are the consequences of placing it out of the server folder ?